# update statement not working in some forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C# programming. I have created a solution within which i have created three projects in that solution. One project contains the login page. That project is working fine but some of the forms in my other two projects are not working properly. The update statements are not working whereas same update statement format has been used in all of the projects. 
Can anyone atleast give me a hint where I might me wrong?

```
if (frmMode == "Update")
        {
            int RecPos = this.BindingContext[estDataSet, "uoms_v"].Position;
            string DsUOMCode = estDataSet.Tables["UOMS_V"].Rows[RecPos]["UOM_Code"].ToString();
            string TbUOMCode = this.txtUOMCode.Text;
            string SetClause = "";
            if (DsUOMCode != TbUOMCode)
            {
                SetClause = "Set UOM_Code= " + "'" + TbUOMCode + "'";
                //pmacsDataSet.Tables["UOMS"].Rows[RecPos]["UOM_Code"] = TbUOMCode;
            }

            string DsDescp = estDataSet.Tables["UOMS_V"].Rows[RecPos]["Descp"].ToString();
            string TbDescp = this.txtDescp.Text;
            if (DsDescp != TbDescp)
            {
                if (SetClause == "")
                {
                    SetClause = "Set Descp= " + "'" + TbDescp + "'";
                    estDataSet.Tables["UOMS_V"].Rows[RecPos]["Descp"] = TbDescp;
                }
                else
                {
                    SetClause = SetClause + "," + "Descp= " + "'" + TbDescp + "'";
                    estDataSet.Tables["UOMS_V"].Rows[RecPos]["Descp"] = TbDescp;
                }
            }

            string DsRemark = estDataSet.Tables["UOMS_V"].Rows[RecPos]["Remark"].ToString();
            string TbRemark = this.txtRemark.Text;
            if (DsRemark != TbRemark)
            {
                if (SetClause == "")
                {
                    SetClause = "Set Remark= " + "'" + TbRemark + "'";
                    estDataSet.Tables["UOMS_V"].Rows[RecPos]["Remark"] = TbRemark;
                }
                else
                {
                    SetClause = SetClause + "," + "Remark= " + "'" + TbRemark + "'";
                    estDataSet.Tables["UOMS_V"].Rows[RecPos]["Remark"] = TbRemark;
                }
            }

            if (SetClause == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There are no changes in field values to be saved");
            }
            else
            {
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
                string UpdStmt = "Update UOMS_V " + SetClause + " WHERE UOM_Code= " + "'" + DsUOMCode + "'";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(UpdStmt, conn);
                try
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(UpdStmt);
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record successfully updated");
                    estDataSet.Tables["UOMS_V"].Clear();
                    frmQueryMode();
                    btnSave.Enabled = false;
                    btnModify.Enabled = false;
                    btnFind.Enabled = false;
                    btnDelete.Enabled = false;
                    btnSearch.Enabled = true;
                    btnCreate.Enabled = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
```

UOMS is of the form where the update is working. The same code has been used in all the other forms where in some of the form the Binding Context values changes as soon as the text box values changes!

Comment: You could start by telling us exactly what the problem is, or by showing relevant code.

Comment: The Binding Context values changes as soon as text box values changes in the form.

Comment: if (frmMode == "Update")
{
  int RecPos = this.BindingContext[estDataSet, "uoms_v"].Position;
  string DsUOMCode = estDataSet.Tables["UOMS_V"].Rows[RecPos]["UOM_Code"].ToString();
  string TbUOMCode = this.txtUOMCode.Text;
  string SetClause = "";
  if (DsUOMCode != TbUOMCode)
  {
    SetClause = "Set UOM_Code= " + "'" + TbUOMCode + "'";
  }

  This is a part of the code that i have used for updation.

Comment: @ShaivyaSharma You should post any code related to your problem in the description.

Comment: Guys i realy need a solution to this!!!!

Comment: This is some piece of code :) data tables instead of typed business object, SQL injection, no dispose for IDisposable object - my eyes just hurt.

Comment: So what else should i tell you so that you could help me?

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, by building your sql-statement, you are wide open to sql-injection and should parameterize them.  I would suggest going along the lines of what I present below.  Create your Command, start the syntax.  For each field NEEDING to be updated, add it to the list and set it's parameter right away.  At the end, add your WHERE criteria, THEN execute it.

```
int RecPos = this.BindingContext[estDataSet, "uoms_v"].Position;
string DsUOMCode = estDataSet.Tables["UOMS_V"].Rows[RecPos]["UOM_Code"].ToString();
string TbUOMCode = this.txtUOMCode.Text;

string DsDescp = estDataSet.Tables["UOMS_V"].Rows[RecPos]["Descp"].ToString();
string TbDescp = this.txtDescp.Text;

string DsRemark = estDataSet.Tables["UOMS_V"].Rows[RecPos]["Remark"].ToString();
string TbRemark = this.txtRemark.Text;

if (  DsUOMCode == TbUOMCode
   && DsDescp == TbDescp
   && DsRemark == TbRemark ) 
{
   MessageBox( "No changes made" );
   return;
}

MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
string UpdStmt = "update UOMS_V set "
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("", conn);
string AddComma = "";

if (DsUOMCode != TbUOMCode)
{
   // just continue to add the build string
   UpdStmt += " UOM_Code = ?parmUOM_Code ";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "?parmUOM_Code", TbUOMCode );
   // in case any additional components to be updated you can
   // add a "," between each update field component.
   AddComma = ",";  
}

if (DsDescp != TbDescp)
{
   // in case the TbUOMCode had something, add comma BEFORE this field instance
   UpdStmt += AddComma + " Descp = ?parmDescp ";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "?parmDescp", TbDescp );
   // in case any additional components to be updated you can
   // add a "," between each update field component.
   AddComma = ",";  
}

if (DsRemark != TbRemark)
{
   // in case the TbUOMCode had something, add comma BEFORE this field instance
   UpdStmt += AddComma + " Remark = ?parmRemark ";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "?parmRemark", TbRemark );
   // in case you want to add any MORE change columns after this one
   AddComma = ",";  
}

// Now, tack on the WHERE clause...
UpdStmt += " WHERE UOM_Code = ?parmWhereUOMCode "
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "?parmWhereUOMCode", DsUOMCode );

// Now, since we changed the "UpdStmt" value from its original command creation, 
// just update the commandText property.... leave parameters alone
cmd.CommandText = UpdStmt;

// Then apply your try/catch
try
{
   // open the connection
   // execute it... etc
}
catch
{
}
```

ONE ADDITIONAL NOTE...  Where I have the "?parmWhatever", the "?" tells MySQL connection/command handlers that.. You will find a parameter within the command object list and its name reference is "?parmWhatever"... Use ITs value for the actual insert/update.

Now, this may be a bit safer for you, but as I did up-front,  I prevalidated that at least SOMETHING was changed.  So, if you wanted, after that, you could have just written as

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
string UpdStmt = "update UOMS_V " 
               + " set UOM_Code = ?parmUOM_Code, "
               + "     Descp = ?parmDescp, "
               + "     Remark = ?parmRemark "
               + " where UOM_Code = ?parmWhereUOM_Code ";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(UpdStmt, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "?parmUOM_Code", TbUOMCode );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "?parmDescp", TbDescp );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "?parmRemark", TbRemark );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "?parmWhereUOMCode", DsUOMCode );

// Then apply your try/catch
try
{
   // open the connection
   // execute it... etc
}
catch
{
}
```

This may be easier as it just builds out for all 3 possible changes and the WHERE clause all at once.  This should be ok since you know a MINIMUM of ONE column is changed and need to send the update.  So, if only one is changed and the others remain the same, by updating the table and setting one column to the same value it started with, won't HURT anything, yet as you can see makes readability / manageability easier.

Comment: But am unable to figure out why the change in a textbox value immediately gets reflected in a dataset table in one table of the DataSet whereas not in other table of the same dataset.

Comment: That is why i get old value in one form and the changed value in another form using the same type of code to get the value from the DataSet. I believe its seems to be related to some property value which is causes this inconsistency.

Comment: Your advice will be highly appreciated.